# How to send html - css email in MVC 4?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, html-email

In my website, I need to send a data table to the client via email. I want the table in a good format. I've heard that inline style doesn't work on Outlook so I think about CSS.

I have no idea about how to do this. Using `Append` method in the `StringBuilder` class is my only choice. Could you tell me a better way to achieve what I want? Thank you so much.

Comment: You heard incorrectly.  CSS doesn't work on Gmail; you need to use inline styles.

Comment: Really? :( Yah, so do you have a better way to write email content, besides using `StringBuilder`?

Comment: You may have a couple of options, but I'm not sure what you mean by `StringBuilder` being your only choice.  How are you sending the email?  Are you using the `MailMessage` object?  If you control the outgoing mail message you may be able to add a CSS "file" as a `LinkedResource` to that message and reference it accordingly.  Inline styles may be easier, though.

Comment: I mean how write email content effectively. I don't want to concatenate string.

Comment: @Forte_201092: That's a completely different question than the one you asked.  What's wrong with concatenating strings to build other strings?  Is there a particular reason you don't want to do it?  An option there could be to store a template somewhere which can be used in a plain old `string.Format()` and then just populate the template with values.

Comment: Yes, I think concatenating string has so much limitation. It's hard to debug or format. It will be very inconvenient if the email body becomes long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer) for this purpose.
It helps composing Email body using regular ASP.NET MVC views

Comment: Is that a third-party library? Thanks, I'll take a look :)

Comment: Yes, it is. It's very convenient way to create email bodies

Comment: It works! That's great. But I still have one more question. With MvcMailer, I can send a hard-code page. I want to display the mail, then the admin can write some extra thing, click "Send", and everything goes. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Forte_201092: Pass a model to your Razor email template.

Comment: I don't understand the work of MvcMailer. How can it know which view to send, if we just specify the view's name? If I want to send the `Index` view in the `Home` controller, what should I do?